# Manifest: Cannot use 'chrome_settings_overrides' for overriding Chrome homepage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "NAME",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Desc",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "chrome_settings_overrides": {
        "homepage": "blank.html"
    }
}
```

When trying to load that as an unpacked extension, I get the following error:

> Failed to load extension from: D:\Path\To\Extension, Empty dictionary for 'chrome_settings_overrides'.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @wOxxOm [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) it says, that my declaration should work...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at the wrong documentation article.

Comment: It's a bug: https://crbug.com/892213

Comment: @wOxxOm Still? The bug seems to be really old... Do you know what I can do then?

Comment: As the bug's description says you need to specify `search_provider`. P.S. There are hundreds of bugs for extensions accumulated over the last 10 years that aren't fixed yet.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are right! Thanks! If you want, you could publish your solution as an answer, so I can mark it as one.